Can we use “reverse sweep” in football?
A reverse sweep is the case, for example, when two sporting teams play a seven game series in the playoffs of their league, one team wins 3 in a row, followed by the other team winning the final 4.
Normally I see this term in set-based games and sports, so I’m not sure if it’s used for football.

What version of football? What country? The US and UK have very different sporting vocabularies, and other countries also play sports.

Note also that a 'reverse sweep' is something different, a type of batting stroke, in cricket.

In soccer and rugby, I can't think of any tournament that uses a series of games in a "best of 5" or "best of 7".  Games are either decided by a single match, or two matches with cumulative goal scores, or by a league with points. Never by a series in any competition that I can think of.  "reverse sweep" in this sense seems to be mostly American in use. Perhaps there are some examples of a series of games in Gridiron football.  But please clarify to explain what you mean by "football" since it refers to different sports in the UK, US, Aus, and NZ

American football does not have series like that. Baseball, basketball, hockey, sure. Not football.

It is not used in "football" (whether by "football" you mean "soccer" as in the UK, or "rugby" as in New Zealand, or "Gridiron" as in the USA, or "Aussie Rules" as in Australia).  Simply because in the culture of the sports, football competitions aren't decided by a series of matches between two teams, but by single matches (such as the SuperBowl), a knockout tournament (the FA cup) or by a league.
The term is used in the USA in those sports that do play a series of games: basketball and baseball for example.  If someone did decide to have a series of football (or soccer) matches between two teams, then you could use "reverse sweep" for football.
Generally such "series" are not common in British sports, perhaps with the exception of test cricket.  One can speculate why they are more common in the USA. Perhaps it is just the size of the country means that in the days before cheap flights, it would seem a waste to travel across the country only to play a single match. Moreover the risk of injury from playing football matches on successive days is too high. 
